is persistece context necessary to crud aplications?
For CRUD applications where each operation must perform a select operation for the database (except persist), is it necessary to check the persistence context?
Is there a way to avoid searching in the persistence context?

Yes, you can avoid searching in the persistence context by using a StatelessSession in Hibernate.
StatelessSession doesn't utilize the persistence context for caching or tracking entity states.
StatelessSession statelessSession = sessionFactory.openStatelessSession();

You can then use the StatelessSession to perform CRUD operations. These operations will be directly applied to the database without involving the persistence context.
